# How to convert all the memoryview columns to bytes columns in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, psycopg2

I'm retrieving a large amount of data from PostgreSQL with:

```
it = pandas.read_sql_table(table, DB_CONN, chunksize=1000)
```

But Pandas uses the psycopg2 adapter for PostgreSQL, which [returns a `memoryview` instead of bytes for historical reasons](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.python/ceHMsyN_2TE). To my knowledge, there is no option to make psycopg2 return `bytes` instead of a `memoryview`, so I'm stuck with this.

Now, the library I'm giving the Pandas dataframe to is written in C and doesn't accept `memoryview` and can only handle `bytes`, so I'd need a way to convert all the `memoryview` columns to `bytes`.

I tried to do this:

```
dataframe[column_name].astype(bytes)
```

but it doesn't work for `memoryview` -> `bytes`, apparently:

```
*** ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

I also tried something like this:

```
dataframe.select_dtypes(include=[memoryview]).apply(bytes)
```

But it doesn't return any columns.

So does anyone know how I can have an **efficient** way of converting **all** the `memoryview` columns of an arbitrary pandas dataframe to `bytes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, apparently when we use a memoryview, Pandas isn't able to recognize that datatype and just stores "object", so I ended up doing something like this:

```
def dataframe_memoryview_to_bytes(dataframe):
    for col in dataframe.columns:
        if type(dataframe[col][0]) == memoryview:
            dataframe[col] = dataframe[col].apply(bytes)
    return dataframe
```

It's really not ideal, and probably not very fast, but it seems to work reasonably well.